# Why does my list return characters instead of items?

Tags: python

This is a very basic question but I'm having trouble understanding why this is.

Taking a file with lists separated by new lines, if I use this script...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

fil = open(sys.argv[1])

 for line in fil:
    linearr = line.strip('\n')
    print linearr[0]
```

I get back a "[" (the first character of the list, the beginning bracket).

Why does this print this character instead of the first item in the list? Is it because the lists already exist in the file and you're not making them within the script?

The lists look like this...

```
['fig|357276.26.peg.4402', 'COG0776']
```

and it should print the first item but doesn't.

Comment: You perform a string method on it, and then wonder why it behaves like a string?

Answer (score -1):

linearr is a string. You are returning the first char in the string. Did you mean to do split()? Split is what you need for making an array out of a string.

Comment: *Split is what you need for making an array out of a string.* that's sort of true, but not what OP is looking for

Comment: He wants a list parsed from each line (which is a string ) so he can get the first entry. He should do the strip (including the brackets), then do a split at the ',' to get the first entry. Not sure what you mean he is looking for.